# populate time range night times php

Tags: php, datetime

i have a open time and a close time. With these 2 vars i populate a timerange with a interval of 30 minutes using this code:

```
function getTimeRange($open,$closed) {
  //$begin = new DateTime($open);
  $begin = new DateTime($open);
  $end   = new DateTime($closed);
  $interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('30 min');
  $times    = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval, $end);
  $timeRange = [];
  foreach ($times as $time) {
    $timeRange[] = $time->add($interval)->format('H:i');
  }
  return $timeRange;
}
```

It works fine but sometimes my open times are in the night. so from 10:00 to 3:00. I have made it so that my software understands that if a store is open till 2:00 it sets the day as the day before... so if its monday 15:00 to 2:00 ... 2am is still monday.

But now for this time range code i need something like that also, but i dont know how to approach this. Because when you put in open: 10:00 closed: 23:59 it works fine but when u change the end time to 2:00 it does nothing.

if a end time is like... 00:00 to 04:00 I want to make a range  and see this as 1 day

//UPDATE AFTER MAGUS AWNSER
hard coding dit not work. But in the class i removed "namespace Carbon;"  at top.. then all worked, your code also excelent!

but now im getting errors like;

```
Warning: The use statement with non-compound name 'DateTime' has no effect in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/r/classes/class.Carbon.php on line 14
Warning: The use statement with non-compound name 'DateTimeZone' has no effect in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/r/classes/class.Carbon.php on line 15
Warning: The use statement with non-compound name 'InvalidArgumentException' has no effect in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/r/classes/class.Carbon.php on line 16
```

I dont know what the meaning of this is... if i also comment out:

```
//namespace Carbon;

//use DateTime;
//use DateTimeZone;
//use InvalidArgumentException;
```

then all works no error... so i don't know if this can cause problems?

Comment: It is not easy to see what you are asking. What is the significance of the 30 minute interval? Please include the code that calls this function, and give us an idea of what output you are expecting.

Comment: i just call this function and insert 2 times... a restaurant openings time and a restaurant closing time...... and what i insert is for example 10:00 and 2:00 ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you using carbon!
https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon

Your function would look something like this:

```
<?php
function getTimeRange($open,$closed) {
    $begin = Carbon::createFromFormat('H:i', $open); //assuming 20:00 here
    $end   = Carbon::createFromFormat('H:i', $closed); //assuming 04:00 here
    //Checking if $closed is in the same day!
    if(intval(explode(':',$open)[0]) > intval(explode(':',$closed)[0]){
        //Truth means that 20 > 4, so $closed should be the next day!
        $end->addDay();
    }
    //I didnt really understood what you wanted here but im guessing
    //you want some sort of array like ['20:00','20:30','21:00',...]
    $halfTimes = $begin->diffInHours($end) * 2;
    $timeRange = [];
    for($i=0;$i<$halfTimes;$i++){
        $begin->addMinutes(30);
        $timeRange[] = $begin->format('H:i');
    }
    return $timeRange;
}
```

Comment: im trying this but for some reason if in include class.Carbon.php in my classes folder... spl_autoload_register can not load it for some reason?

Comment: try hardcoding the require(file) to check where if the error is in the autoload_register or in the class

Comment: That would just be a simple warning. See, the 'namespace' and 'use' are more for an OO project, using composer to get the Carbon packages and some other fancy (and goddamn useful) things. Without them, your code should run fine, don't worry ;)